# Pythonic way to pass a method to another function

Tags: python, styles, multiple-inheritance

I'm unsure the best way to do the following. That is, I'm not sure if I should have a parent class UniSamplingStrategy and child classes UniformSampling, and RandomSampling. Or should I just have UniSamplingStrategy and have the types of samplings as methods? For example, this is what I did:

```
import numpy as np

## make a base class w/ child classes instead?
class UniSamplingStrategy():
    def __init__(self, 
                 left=0, 
                 right=0,
                 num_samples=0, 
                 cluster_center=None, 
                 defined_array=[0]
                ):
    
        self._left = left
        self._right = right
        self._num_samples = num_samples
        self._cluster_center = cluster_center
        self._defined_array = defined_array

   # uniform sampling
   def uniform_sampling(self):
        return np.linspace(start=self._left, 
                           stop=self._right, 
                           num=self._num_samples, 
                           endpoint=True, 
                           dtype=np.float32)

   # random spacing
   def clustered_sampling(self):
        return np.random.normal(loc=self._clust_center, 
                                scale=(self._right - self._left)/4, 
                                size=self._num_samples)
```

What I want to do with this class (or perhaps classes, if I need to rewrite for good python) is pass a sampling strategy to my data_generation method.

```
def data_generation(noise_scale, 
                    sampling_strategy, 
                    test_func,
                    noise_type
                   ):

    x_samples = sampling_strategy
    y_samples = test_func(x=x_samples)


    if noise_type is not None:
        _, y_samples_noise = noise_type(x=x_samples, scale=noise_scale)
        y_samples = y_samples + y_samples_noise

    return x_samples, y_samples

def test_func(x): 
    return (np.cos(x))**2/((x/6)**2+1)

def hmskd_noise(x, scale):  
    scales = scale
    return scales, np.random.normal(scale=scale, size=x.shape[0])
```

So that ideally, I could try different test functions, noise, and sampling schemes. Where I could write function calls like:

```
x_true, y_true = data_generation(sampling_strategy=uniform_sampling(left=0, right=10, num_samples=1000)
                                 test_func = test_func,
                                 noise_type=None,
                                 noise_scale = 0)

x_obs, y_obs = data_generation(sampling_strategy=clustered_sampling(clustered_center=5, left=0, right=10, num_samples = 20),
                               test_func = test_func,
                               noise_type=hmskd_noise,
                               noise_scale=0.2)
```

Essentially, I'm interested in the best way to pass a sampling strategy to data_generation when each method can have different parameters to pass (e.g., see uniform_sampling and clustered_sampling parameters).

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you have now.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can have a set of classes with __call__ method. Like

```
class UniformSampling:
    def __init__(self, 
                 left=0, 
                 right=0,
                 num_samples=0, 
                 cluster_center=None, 
                 defined_array=[0]
                ):
    
        self._left = left
        self._right = right
        self._num_samples = num_samples
        self._cluster_center = cluster_center
        self._defined_array = defined_array

    def __call__(self, arg1, arg2):
        return np.linspace(start=self._left, 
                            stop=self._right, 
                            num=self._num_samples, 
                            endpoint=True, 
                            dtype=np.float32)
```

Then you can pass instantiated object to **data_generation** as

```
x_true, y_true = data_generation(sampling_strategy=UniformSampling(left=0, right=10, num_samples=1000),
                                 test_func = test_func,
                                 noise_type=None,
                                 noise_scale = 0)
```